# Failed to start the Processing Engine service - Sitecore 9.3 -

Tags: processing

The Processing Engine Service is failing to start either manually or through the service task. I am getting the below error message in the log file:

```
023-11-08 14:11:41.489 -06:00 [Error] Failed to start the Processing Engine service.
Rebus.Injection.ResolutionException: Could not resolve Rebus.Transport.ITransport with decorator depth 0 - registrations: Rebus.Injection.Injectionist+Handler ---> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'messaging'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionProvider.CreateSqlConnectionSuppressingAPossibleAmbientTransaction()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionProvider.<GetConnection>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.<InnerEnsureTableIsCreatedAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.<EnsureTableIsCreatedAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.<<Run>b__7_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.Run()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.RunSync(Func`1 task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.EnsureTableIsCreated()
   at Rebus.Config.SqlServerTransportConfigurationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Configure>b__0(IResolutionContext context)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c.<Start>b__12_12(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Start>b__25(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Start>b__26(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.OptionsConfigurerExtensions.<>c.<DecorateUsingRetryerBus>b__0_0(IResolutionContext ctx)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.Start()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageServiceBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<AddBuses>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageBusRegistry.EnsureIsStarted(String busName)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.ServiceProviderExtensions.StartMessageBuses(IServiceProvider provider, String[] busNames)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Hosting.AgentHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(String[] args)
```

We have not updated anything recently, however, it could be related to some security restrictions. I have not found any similar case in this blog.

Thoughts?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you share any relevant connection strings? Does the Processing Engine service have the necessary permissions to access the database?

Comment: Thank you, Marcel. Certainly, the DB user has all the necessary permissions to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** First of all, check if you have a valid Sitecore License.

**Solution 2:**
If yes, then you can check the below -

1. Run Powershell as Administrator.
2. Run the below command to check for any Non-Self-Signed Certificates.

   `Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}`
3. If the above line returns any certificates, as a result. Run the below command to move these non-self-signed certificates into the Intermediate Certification Authorities store.

   `Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA`

For reference - https://www.vinayjadav.com/posts/sitecore-installation-failed-to-start-marketing-automation-engine

**Solution 3:** Another reason why you would get the marketing automation service start error is a difference in the target .net framework.
For this you can follow this - https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2020/12/sitecore-10-sif-installation-failed-to.html

Comment: Thank you, Gaurav,
the PS command that works is this:
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Select Issuer,Thumbprint, Subject | Where-Object {$_.Subject -ne $_.Issuer}
however, the result did not return anything.